# Rewriting a Select Into with Insert statment so that the tables are not locked during the execution of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone know how this query can be rewritten using Insert Statement instead of select Into

```
exec('SELECT TOP (0) * INTO [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] FROM [' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']')
```

Comment: You probably get an error if you try to run it twice, correct?

Comment: I am just wondering if the insert into locks the tables involved during the duration of the query

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  The query you have appears to create a copy of the source table *(without constraints, indexes, triggers, etc)*.  Are you trying to find an alternative way of making this copy, or trying to find the correct syntax to insert into it after you've created the copy?  Or perhaps something else?  To be really clear it's often best to state what you're trying to achieve in the broader picture, as well as the problems you're having with the solutions you've tried.

Comment: Yes, it does lock the tables. All operations that modify the contents of a table (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) are table-locking queries.

Comment: This query just used to create a new table **DestinationTable**  with same structure as **SourceTable**

Comment: CREATE TABLE is only option. `SELECT INTO` cannot be replaced with `INSERT INTO`

Comment: Hi All i was trying to find a way to produce a non table locking commands.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `WITH NOLOCK`:

```
EXEC('INSERT INTO [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] SELECT TOP(0) * FROM [' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + '] WITH (NOLOCK)')
```

Comment: It's unclear what the OP is requesting.  This is syntax to insert into the table, though with exactly 0 rows, but does not create the destination table.  I *think* the OP still wants to create the destination table (which is what `SELECT INTO` is normally used for, especially with `TOP(0)`.).